# NetStat Group By Process Id and Show Count

Tags: windows, port, netstat

Is there any way to group the output given by netstat into process? I am running `netstat -ano` and doing manual count to know which process is using how many ports. I am using Windows Server.

We have port exhaustion issue and we want to know which find which process is using most of ports quickly?

Like,
Process Id 1 is using 100 ports
Process Id 2 is using 20 ports
and so on

Answer (score 0):

I have found PowerShell for this,

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Group-Object -Property State, OwningProcess | Select -Property Count, Name, @{Name="ProcessName";Expression={(Get-Process -PID ($_.Name.Split(',')[-1].Trim(' '))).Name}}, Group | Sort Count -Descending
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcp-ip-port-exhaustion-troubleshooting?source=recommendations